# Adding script as string into textarea value

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is pretty self explanatory. What I want to do is changing the value of a textarea with jQuery. What I do is:

```
$( '#embedcode' ).val( "<script id='embed_1' src='/javascripts/test.js' type='text/javascript'></script>" );
```

What is the right way to do that. I keep getting an error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

How to make the  that I want to add as a string not a script.

Comment: I revised my answer with some information I believe you will find helpful in understanding this issue and the answers provided. Give it another look (the paragraph at the end).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

Make your String like this :

```
$('#embedcode').val("<script id='embed_1' src='\/javascripts\/test.js' type='text\/javascript'><\/script>");
```

Check out this JsFiddle i made for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/KB9Qn/14/

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to work perfectly. Here's the live demo: [Click here](http://jsbin.com/oLURoVu/1/edit)

You need to check the line number where you are getting that error.

edit: I just had the thought. If your html markup has an error (maybe an unclosed textarea) the script can be evaluated as a script tag rather than text. Check for that. [Here is a live example of an html error that will cause your problem. Click here.](http://jsbin.com/oLURoVu/3/edit)

Update: I believe I know exactly what the real issue is. The other posts are recommending that you escape the '<' and '>', but that should only be necessary if this javascript you are using is actually in an html file (or html generated by the server) rather than in a js file where it belongs. In the js file, it will naturally be a string as you have written it, but the html file sees it as markup even though it isn't intended to be. This is an example of why you should follow the best practices and keep javascript in a js file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the "<" and ">".

```
$('#embedcode').val("\<script id='embed_1' src='/javascripts/test.js' type='text/javascript'\>\</script\>");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/whyach/cN7ky/)

Answer (score 2):

escape the `<` and `>` in the string with `\`